# What's wrong if "Deletion log file could not be created: No authorization"?

Tags: permissions, samba, users, trash

On my Lubuntu 16.04 I connected to my NAS and was not able to delete files. The error message was something like:

```
Deletion log file could not be created: No authorization.
```

My connection to the share is established through:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=USERSERVER,uid=LOCALUSER,gid=LOCALGROUP,username=USERSERVER,password=PW //192.168.0.102/RAID6 /media/OMV
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can run commands with modified environment, so whenever you need to output error in English, do `LC_ALL=C  command arg1 arg2`

Comment: Thanks for this comment, which related to the fact that I originally stated the error in german: "Löschprotokolldatei konnte nicht angelegt werden". I still find this usefull to be in here, because there is practically no evidence of this error findable via google in german at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: How did you try to delete?

Comment: Fron inside PCmanFM, which is the file manager from Lubuntu, on a share that was mounted via samba.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because I did not find a lot on the internet about it I wanted to share my solution and keep the german original error message, which is "Löschprotokolldatei konnte nicht angelegt werden".

Somehow, the (hidden) folder `SHARENAME/.Trash-1000` was owned by a different user than the one I used when connecting to the share. As soon as I fixed this on the NAS (over ssh) with `sudo chown -R USER:GROUP FOLDER` I was able to delete again from inside my filemanager that was connected to the share.

Comment: On some systems, the `-R` flag in chown must be capitalized, or it'll error out about `-r` not being proper usage.

Comment: thanks, I might have twisted it with 'cp -r'. Corrected it in the answer.